# Processing Large Files in Python [ 1000 GB or More]

Tags: python, performance, file, python-2.7, text

Lets say i have a text file of 1000 GB. I need to find how much times a phrase occurs in the text.

Is there any faster way to do this that the one i am using bellow?
How much would it take to complete the task.

```
phrase = "how fast it is"
count = 0
with open('bigfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        count += line.count(phrase)
```

If I am right if I do not have this file in the memory i would meed to wait till the PC loads the file each time I am doing the search and this should take at least 4000 sec for a 250 MB/sec hard drive and a file of 10000 GB.

Comment: `grep` would _certainly_ be faster then `python`.

Comment: Your code doesn't currently handle the case that the phrase is split across multiple lines within the file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are you going to suggest slurping the entire file into memory?

Comment: @devnull I hadn't planned to! Just pointing out something to think about.

Comment: I do not actually have the case where the phrase is in multiple lines.

Comment: are there any constraints on using multi-threading? do you have multiple CPU cores available?

Comment: If I am right if I do not have this file in the memory unless it is zipped or something the i would wait till the PC loads the file and this should take at least 40 sec for 250 MB/sec hard drive.

Comment: I could use multithreading but the core problem is how to compressthe file so it could get loaded inmax 5 sec. Maybe database.

Comment: you might want to read the file in larger chunks rather than lines to benefit from the disk caches. and if you have multiple cores you can try to interleave reading and searching to keep the machine busy.

Comment: Lines itself are pretty large but that is a good sugestion. thanks

Comment: @Brana Don't accept any solution if you are not entirely satisfied with them. After 2 days I'll raise a bounty on this question, that might inspire people to post some awesome answers. :)

Comment: Are you going to perform queries several times? Would it be worth spending a long time compressing the file once?

Comment: Multithreading won't help with IO bottleneck, at best, it would make your program more complex, at worse, your harddisk head would be trashing around and you'll get much slower read speed. If you really need to process this file as fast as possible, you need to split the file to multiple harddisks. This can be achieved either by using multiple harddisks in a RAID configuration or by processing the file in parallel in multiple machines and then aggregating the results into one.

Comment: I thought to parse all the 3-grams 4 and 5-grams from the file and then to save and sort them into small files. The names of the files would start with first 3 chars of the ngrams. So I would have around 300 000 files where each file has around 150MB (some would probably be 4-5 times larger).

Comment: Yes i perform queries all the time, buy i think the engram solutions is the only possible because of the load time.

Comment: @Brana I think you should edit your original question to specify that you're going to perform many searches for phrases (which it seems will be limited to 3-5 words?) against this file, since it significantly changes how folks are going to answer.

Comment: I am not sure if i should change the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used `file.read()` to read the data in chunks, in current examples the chunks were of size 100 MB, 500MB, 1GB and 2GB respectively. The size of my text file is 2.1 GB.

**Code:**

```
 from functools import partial

 def read_in_chunks(size_in_bytes):

    s = 'Lets say i have a text file of 1000 GB'
    with open('data.txt', 'r+b') as f:
        prev = ''
        count = 0
        f_read  = partial(f.read, size_in_bytes)
        for text in iter(f_read, ''):
            if not text.endswith('\n'):
                # if file contains a partial line at the end, then don't
                # use it when counting the substring count. 
                text, rest = text.rsplit('\n', 1)
                # pre-pend the previous partial line if any.
                text =  prev + text
                prev = rest
            else:
                # if the text ends with a '\n' then simple pre-pend the
                # previous partial line. 
                text =  prev + text
                prev = ''
            count += text.count(s)
        count += prev.count(s)
        print count
```

**Timings:**

```
read_in_chunks(104857600)
$ time python so.py
10000000

real    0m1.649s
user    0m0.977s
sys     0m0.669s

read_in_chunks(524288000)
$ time python so.py
10000000

real    0m1.558s
user    0m0.893s
sys     0m0.646s

read_in_chunks(1073741824)
$ time python so.py
10000000

real    0m1.242s
user    0m0.689s
sys     0m0.549s


read_in_chunks(2147483648)
$ time python so.py
10000000

real    0m0.844s
user    0m0.415s
sys     0m0.408s
```

On the other hand the simple loop version takes around 6 seconds on my system:

```
def simple_loop():

    s = 'Lets say i have a text file of 1000 GB'
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        print sum(line.count(s) for line in f)

$ time python so.py
10000000

real    0m5.993s
user    0m5.679s
sys     0m0.313s
```

---

Results of @SlaterTyranus's [`grep` version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23765585/846892) on my file:

```
$ time grep -o 'Lets say i have a text file of 1000 GB' data.txt|wc -l
10000000

real    0m11.975s
user    0m11.779s
sys     0m0.568s
```

---

Results of @woot's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23838307/846892):

```
$ time cat data.txt | parallel --block 10M --pipe grep -o 'Lets\ say\ i\ have\ a\ text\ file\ of\ 1000\ GB' | wc -l
10000000

real    0m5.955s
user    0m14.825s
sys     0m5.766s
```

Got best timing when I used 100 MB as block size:

```
$ time cat data.txt | parallel --block 100M --pipe grep -o 'Lets\ say\ i\ have\ a\ text\ file\ of\ 1000\ GB' | wc -l
10000000

real    0m4.632s
user    0m13.466s
sys     0m3.290s
```

---

Results of woot's [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839675/846892):

```
$ time python woot_thread.py # CHUNK_SIZE = 1073741824
10000000

real    0m1.006s
user    0m0.509s
sys     0m2.171s
$ time python woot_thread.py  #CHUNK_SIZE = 2147483648
10000000

real    0m1.009s
user    0m0.495s
sys     0m2.144s
```

<sub>**System Specs**: Core i5-4670, 7200 RPM HDD</sub>

Comment: It is a much faster. But the sped is limited by the hard drive speed. Any way to compress the file significantly - like from 1000 GB to 1 GB. Maybe using database.

Comment: @Brana No idea about that compression stuff. :/

Comment: this is however the fastest so far. Could it be added in a database and be faster.

Comment: It's worthwhile to point out that `grep` efficiency depends upon the locale.  Set `LANG=C` before executing `grep` and you might notice a difference in the time.

Comment: @devnull Just tested it, now it got even slower. Took around 17s. seconds.

Comment: I will use this solution to load the files, and also I will have to to make 3-5 words engrams out of the original file which should be 1000-5000 GB and then make many files - probably around 100 000 files of around 50MB in size which name begins as the first few letters of the engrams. Other solutions where I have to read through the whole file in parts are good, but too slow and i would need some raid of 1000's of SSD drives to be able to get the result in one second or less.

Comment: This solution is called cache blocking. It is fast because you reduce the number of times you get a cache miss. Try to use this approach with respect to your cache size. I have no idea how to find the appropriate cache size in python.

Comment: excuse me can you help in this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147009/how-to-handle-file-with-3-gb-without-increasing-ram-with-this-code

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Python attempt...  You might need to play with the THREADS and CHUNK_SIZE.  Also it's a bunch of code in a short time so I might not have thought of everything. I do overlap my buffer though to catch the ones in between, and I extend the last chunk to include the remainder of the file.

```
import os
import threading

INPUTFILE ='bigfile.txt'
SEARCH_STRING='how fast it is'
THREADS = 8  # Set to 2 times number of cores, assuming hyperthreading
CHUNK_SIZE = 32768

FILESIZE = os.path.getsize(INPUTFILE)
SLICE_SIZE = FILESIZE / THREADS



class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, filehandle, seekspot):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.filehandle = filehandle
        self.seekspot = seekspot
        self.cnt = 0
    def run(self):
        self.filehandle.seek( self.seekspot )

        p = self.seekspot
        if FILESIZE - self.seekspot < 2 * SLICE_SIZE:
            readend = FILESIZE
        else: 
            readend = self.seekspot + SLICE_SIZE + len(SEARCH_STRING) - 1
        overlap = ''
        while p < readend:
            if readend - p < CHUNK_SIZE:
                buffer = overlap + self.filehandle.read(readend - p)
            else:
                buffer = overlap + self.filehandle.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            if buffer:
                self.cnt += buffer.count(SEARCH_STRING)
            overlap = buffer[len(buffer)-len(SEARCH_STRING)+1:]
            p += CHUNK_SIZE

filehandles = []
threads = []
for fh_idx in range(0,THREADS):
    filehandles.append(open(INPUTFILE,'rb'))
    seekspot = fh_idx * SLICE_SIZE
    threads.append(myThread(filehandles[fh_idx],seekspot ) )
    threads[fh_idx].start()

totalcount = 0 
for fh_idx in range(0,THREADS):
    threads[fh_idx].join()
    totalcount += threads[fh_idx].cnt

print totalcount
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at using [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) / [grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/)?

```
cat bigfile.txt | parallel --block 10M --pipe grep -o 'how\ fast\ it\ is' | wc -l
```

Comment: I just tested it on my Linux VM and it worked. What error are you getting?  Also, I added -o and | wc -l to more correctly answer the question.

Comment: Sorry 1 sec I know what is wrong.  I'll edit to make it work for all.

Comment: It took around 4.6 seconds when I raised it to 100M(which is 100 MB if I am not wrong), anything above or below that was slower compared to it.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what to set that number to.  You also might be able to oversubscribe with the --j N, where N is 2x number of cores to account for hyperthreading.

Comment: I tried with `--j 8` and `--j 4`, but no noticeable improvement. It's still 4.6 seconds.(I've 4 core processor)

Comment: Yeah. parallel does a pretty good job at picking the right number, but it was worth a shot. Have you tried out the multithreaded Python approach?  I'm curious how that times on your tests.

Comment: I added the results to my answer, it's pretty close to my solution's timing.

Comment: Probably just I/O bound at this point and all the threading is just noise.  I do similar parallel operations on much larger machines with fast I/O with good results.  If @Brana plans to run these searches with different search criteria very frequently, there are probably better approaches that involve reorganizing the data.

Comment: If you are case insensitivity you can use `LANG=C grep`. you can also use `--mmap` with parallel. It will improve drastically the overall speed.

Answer (score 4):

Had you considered indexing your file? The way search engine works is by creating a mapping from words to the location they are in the file. Say if you have this file:

```
Foo bar baz dar. Dar bar haa.
```

You create an index that looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": {0},
    "bar": {4, 21},
    "baz": {8},
    "dar": {12, 17},
    "haa": {25},
}
```

A hashtable index can be looked up in O(1); so it's freaking fast.

And someone searches for the query "bar baz" you first break the query into its constituent words: ["bar", "baz"] and you then found {4, 21}, {8}; then you use this to jump out right to the places where the queried text could possible exists.

There are out of the box solutions for indexed search engines as well; for example [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Comment: This is interesting. I need position in sentence as well as position of the sentence in the file to be able to do engram search. But it seems only to make the search faster and it probably can't compress the file. What i do instead is simply write all 2 3 and 4 and 5 grams in more than 10 000 files with the name corresponding to the letters on the beginning of the engram.

Answer (score 2):

Going to suggest doing this with `grep` instead of python. Will be faster, and generally if you're dealing with 1000GB of text on your local machine you've done something wrong, but all judgements aside, `grep` comes with a couple of options that will make your life easier.

```
grep -o '<your_phrase>' bigfile.txt|wc -l
```

Specifically this will count the number of lines in which your desired phrase appears. This should also count multiple occurrences on a single line.

If you don't need that you could instead do something like this:

```
grep -c '<your_phrase>' bigfile.txt
```

Comment: @lejlot All of the text on wikipedia combined is multiple orders of magnitude less than 1000 GB. There is not a text corpus on the planet larger than a few hundred gigs and that's Google's text corpus of the entire internet. Text is tiny.

Comment: OP is asking a typical Google interview questions. Google has enough data so that the question still kinda makes sense.

Comment: @Slater, sorry, you are right, wiki is "just" 44 GB

Comment: @lejlot And much smaller than that when omitting stubs, duplicates, and multiple languages.

Comment: @Pavel 'local machine' then being the operative phrase. Google would want you to do this on a compute cluster and then this would be a totally different question.

Comment: ...now you're speculating :)

Comment: @Pavel Now you *think* I'm speculating :)

Comment: But the processing time even if i use  grep should be more than 1000GB/ drive speed which is around 500 MB/sec. So it is around 20 sesc?

Comment: @Brana Yes, you will be limited by your hard drive's read speed regardless of how you represent this data. May I suggest getting some aws compute space? Alternatively, I'm willing to bet you don't need to search the full 1000GB. You could search some decently-sized random sample and assume the frequency is representative.

Comment: I will remove all duplicated but still I will be licky if i get less than 1000GB since I am planning to have around 150 sizes of wikipedia.

Comment: @Brana Without knowing more about your specific application I can't really help. You will be I/O bound by your hardware, and that's a pretty hard limit.

Comment: See example "friendly skin moisturizer" site:edu there are results and "friendly skin moisturizer" site:wikipedia.org - there are no results.

Comment: @Brana What are you saying in that last comment?

Comment: Yes you need to google "friendly skin moisturizer" site:edu as well as "friendly skin moisturizer" site:wikipedia.org. In first case there are and i second there are no results. So wikipedia is to small and all edu sites for example are enough.

Comment: I guess i could make an list of nrams (2, 3 and four) with their frequencies. This should result in a smaller file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a third, longer method that uses a database.  The database is sure to be larger than the text.  I am not sure about if the indexes is optimal, and some space savings could come from playing with that a little.  (like, maybe WORD, and POS, WORD are better, or perhaps WORD, POS is just fine, need to experiment a little).

This may not perform well on 200 OK's test though because it is a lot of repeating text, but might perform well on more unique data.

First create a database by scanning the words, etc:

```
import sqlite3
import re

INPUT_FILENAME = 'bigfile.txt'
DB_NAME = 'words.db'
FLUSH_X_WORDS=10000


conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)
cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDS (
     POS INTEGER
    ,WORD TEXT
    ,PRIMARY KEY( POS, WORD )
) WITHOUT ROWID
""")

cursor.execute("""
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS I_WORDS_WORD_POS
""")

cursor.execute("""
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS I_WORDS_POS_WORD
""")


cursor.execute("""
DELETE FROM WORDS
""")

conn.commit()

def flush_words(words):
    for word in words.keys():
        for pos in words[word]:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO WORDS (POS, WORD) VALUES( ?, ? )', (pos, word.lower()) )

    conn.commit()

words = dict()
pos = 0
recomp = re.compile('\w+')
with open(INPUT_FILENAME, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        for word in [x.lower() for x in recomp.findall(line) if x]:
            pos += 1
            if words.has_key(word):
                words[word].append(pos)
            else:
                words[word] = [pos]
        if pos % FLUSH_X_WORDS == 0:
            flush_words(words)
            words = dict()
    if len(words) > 0:
        flush_words(words)
        words = dict()


cursor.execute("""
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_WORDS_WORD_POS ON WORDS ( WORD, POS )
""")

cursor.execute("""
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_WORDS_POS_WORD ON WORDS ( POS, WORD )
""")

cursor.execute("""
VACUUM
""")

cursor.execute("""
ANALYZE WORDS
""")
```

Then search the database by generating SQL:

```
import sqlite3
import re

SEARCH_PHRASE = 'how fast it is'
DB_NAME = 'words.db'


conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_NAME)
cursor = conn.cursor()

recomp = re.compile('\w+')

search_list = [x.lower() for x in recomp.findall(SEARCH_PHRASE) if x]

from_clause = 'FROM\n'
where_clause = 'WHERE\n'
num = 0
fsep = '     '
wsep = '     '
for word in search_list:
    num += 1
    from_clause += '{fsep}words w{num}\n'.format(fsep=fsep,num=num)
    where_clause += "{wsep} w{num}.word = '{word}'\n".format(wsep=wsep, num=num, word=word)
    if num > 1:
        where_clause += "  AND w{num}.pos = w{lastnum}.pos + 1\n".format(num=str(num),lastnum=str(num-1))

    fsep = '    ,'
    wsep = '  AND'


sql = """{select}{fromc}{where}""".format(select='SELECT COUNT(*)\n',fromc=from_clause, where=where_clause)

res = cursor.execute( sql )

print res.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: NP, hope one of these approaches helped.  I am sure there is an even better version of this that could be implemented, there are plenty of search string algorithms, you just need one that can work on disk efficiently.

Comment: I will first use the 200 OK solution and then try to use the your multithresding sp;utiom to improve the speed.

Comment: This is also great solution for smaller files i will try with the solution wwith txt files since it is easier to have multiple files than multiple databases.

Answer (score 2):

We're talking about a simple count of a specific substring within a rather large data stream. The task is nearly certainly I/O bound, but very easily parallelised. The first layer is the raw read speed; we can choose to reduce the read amount by using compression, or distribute the transfer rate by storing the data in multiple places. Then we have the search itself; substring searches are a well known problem, again I/O limited. If the data set comes from a single disk pretty much any optimisation is moot, as there's no way that disk beats a single core in speed.

Assuming we do have chunks, which might for instance be the separate blocks of a bzip2 file (if we use a threaded decompressor), stripes in a RAID, or distributed nodes, we have much to gain from processing them individually. Each chunk is searched for `needle`, then joints can be formed by taking `len(needle)-1` from the end of one chunk and beginning of the next, and searching within those.

A quick benchmark demonstrates that the regular expression state machines operate faster than the usual `in` operator:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("x.search(s)", "s='a'*500000; import re; x=re.compile('foobar')", number=20000)
17.146117210388184
>>> timeit.timeit("'foobar' in s", "s='a'*500000", number=20000)
24.263535976409912
>>> timeit.timeit("n in s", "s='a'*500000; n='foobar'", number=20000)
21.562405109405518
```

Another step of optimization we can perform, given that we have the data in a file, is to [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) it instead of using the usual read operations. This permits the operating system to use the disk buffers directly. It also allows the kernel to satisfy multiple read requests in arbitrary order without making extra system calls, which lets us exploit things like an underlying RAID when operating in multiple threads.

Here's a quickly tossed together prototype. A few things could obviously be improved, such as distributing the chunk processes if we have a multinode cluster, doing the tail+head check by passing one to the neighboring worker (an order which is not known in this implementation) instead of sending both to a special worker, and implementing an interthread limited queue (pipe) class instead of matching semaphores. It would probably also make sense to move the worker threads outside of the main thread function, since the main thread keeps altering its locals.

```
from mmap import mmap, ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY, ACCESS_READ
from re import compile, escape
from threading import Semaphore, Thread
from collections import deque

def search(needle, filename):
    # Might want chunksize=RAID block size, threads
    chunksize=ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY*1024
    threads=32
    # Read chunk allowance
    allocchunks=Semaphore(threads)  # should maybe be larger
    chunkqueue=deque()   # Chunks mapped, read by workers
    chunksready=Semaphore(0)
    headtails=Semaphore(0)   # edges between chunks into special worker
    headtailq=deque()
    sumq=deque()     # worker final results

    # Note: although we do push and pop at differing ends of the
    # queues, we do not actually need to preserve ordering. 

    def headtailthread():
        # Since head+tail is 2*len(needle)-2 long, 
        # it cannot contain more than one needle
        htsum=0
        matcher=compile(escape(needle))
        heads={}
        tails={}
        while True:
            headtails.acquire()
            try:
                pos,head,tail=headtailq.popleft()
            except IndexError:
                break  # semaphore signaled without data, end of stream
            try:
                prevtail=tails.pop(pos-chunksize)
                if matcher.search(prevtail+head):
                    htsum+=1
            except KeyError:
                heads[pos]=head
            try:
                nexthead=heads.pop(pos+chunksize)
                if matcher.search(tail+nexthead):
                    htsum+=1
            except KeyError:
                tails[pos]=tail
        # No need to check spill tail and head as they are shorter than needle
        sumq.append(htsum)

    def chunkthread():
        threadsum=0
        # escape special characters to achieve fixed string search
        matcher=compile(escape(needle))
        borderlen=len(needle)-1
        while True:
            chunksready.acquire()
            try:
                pos,chunk=chunkqueue.popleft()
            except IndexError:   # End of stream
                break
            # Let the re module do the heavy lifting
            threadsum+=len(matcher.findall(chunk))
            if borderlen>0:
                # Extract the end pieces for checking borders
                head=chunk[:borderlen]
                tail=chunk[-borderlen:]
                headtailq.append((pos,head,tail))
                headtails.release()
            chunk.close()
            allocchunks.release()  # let main thread allocate another chunk
        sumq.append(threadsum)

    with infile=open(filename,'rb'):
        htt=Thread(target=headtailthread)
        htt.start()
        chunkthreads=[]
        for i in range(threads):
            t=Thread(target=chunkthread)
            t.start()
            chunkthreads.append(t)
        pos=0
        fileno=infile.fileno()
        while True:
            allocchunks.acquire()
            chunk=mmap(fileno, chunksize, access=ACCESS_READ, offset=pos)
            chunkqueue.append((pos,chunk))
            chunksready.release()
            pos+=chunksize
            if pos>chunk.size():   # Last chunk of file?
                break
        # File ended, finish all chunks
        for t in chunkthreads:
            chunksready.release()   # wake thread so it finishes
        for t in chunkthreads:
            t.join()    # wait for thread to finish
        headtails.release()     # post event to finish border checker
        htt.join()
        # All threads finished, collect our sum
        return sum(sumq)

if __name__=="__main__":
    from sys import argv
    print "Found string %d times"%search(*argv[1:])
```

Also, modifying the whole thing to use some mapreduce routine (map chunks to counts, heads and tails, reduce by summing counts and checking tail+head parts) is left as an exercise.

Edit: Since it seems this search will be repeated with varying needles, an index would be much faster, being able to skip searches of sections that are known not to match. One possibility is making a map of which blocks contain any occurence of various n-grams (accounting for the block borders by allowing the ngram to overlap into the next); those maps can then be combined to find more complex conditions, before the blocks of original data need to be loaded. There are certainly databases to do this; look for full text search engines.

Comment: And I just noticed.. mmap will fail on the last block if the file isn't exactly a multiple of the chunk size. We need to read the file size first and reduce the size for the last chunk.

Comment: The ngram indices themselves could be reduced in size by making them Bloom filters.

Comment: This is a cool solution. I could so one that would be even simpler if I name the files after the first 5 letters or an engram. I would have pairs in line like this: "engram","frequency". For example:"small red shoes,"122".

Answer (score 1):

I concede that grep will be be faster.  I assume this file is a large string based file.

But you could do something like this if you really really wanted.

```
import os
import re
import mmap

fileName = 'bigfile.txt'
phrase = re.compile("how fast it is")

with open(fileName, 'r') as fHandle:
    data = mmap.mmap(fHandle.fileno(), os.path.getsize(fileName), access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    matches = re.match(phrase, data)
    print('matches = {0}'.format(matches.group()))
```

Comment: More explanation would be more useful. Also a speed comparison on a smaller file. Also regex is extremely slow.

Comment: This one doesn't load file. I tested it: